# Can't config symfony 2 after installing

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to take my first steps with symfony. I have a xampp 3.1 over windows XP.

I've downloaded Symfony 2.3.3 with vendors, unzip the package and check my browser: (protocol/hostname)/sfprojects/soma/Symfony/web/config.php

I see the welcome screen, but the following warning is on top:

```
Warning: file_get_contents
(C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\soma\Symfony\app/../vendor/sensio/distributionbundle/
Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/skeleton/app/SymfonyRequirements.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\soma\Symfony\app\SymfonyRequirements.php on line 534
```

On the bottom, there's a link: Configure your app online. When I click, the following error occurs:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.1/1 FatalErrorException: Error: 
Class 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle' 
not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\soma\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 18
in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\soma\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 18
```

The appKernel file looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
    $bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
);
```

I've found the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.php file at C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\soma\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle

It's a fresh install, I haven't modified anything. I dont' think it may be related, but I have other folders with others symfony releases, neither woring.

Any clues about what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've spend half a day analizing this and I found many paths are wrong, for instance:
SymfonyRequirements.php __DIR__.'/../vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/skeleton/app/SymfonyRequirements.php dosen't work. I've changed temporarily for file_get_contents(__FILE__) === file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Resources\skeleton\app\SymfonyRequirements.php'), and then can go on, but then a new error and I had to add to AppKernel the line namespace Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle; and so on. yet not workin

Comment: The symfony tar is unzipped in C:\xampp\htdocs .

Comment: Perhaps, sensio vendor files were not properly generated. If composer.phar misses any file, you can copy them manually.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some problems with the `.tar.gz` version on Windows. Prefer using the `.zip` version on Windows if you don’t want to use Composer.